Switch Mode Power Supply Stability Analysis for Cascaded Converters / Filters, Loading Conditions
When putting switch mode supplies in series with each other, or adding an input filter to a supply, I have used the Middlebrook criteria to check for stability.  Chris Basso's other stack exchange posts, and online resources have been of great help in this area (Stack exchange post, Seminar)
What I keep getting a bit confused about is if the loading that's presented by the 2nd-stage should be allowed to damp the first stage when simulating or calculating output impedance in isolation.  For example, on page 156 of the seminar linked to above, Basso shows that the first converter's output impedance is calculated with an Rload of 8.3Ohms.  The lower this Rload, the lower output impedance will be.  I assume this is a load presented by the downstream converter.
However, in all of the cases where Middlebrook is checked for input filter design, the representative load resistor (which would nicely damp LC filters without a dedicated damping network) is missing.
My intuition is that it depends on the loading cases that you care about, and for most filter designs, you want to check at light load, in which case it makes sense to pull the equivalent load resistor out of the circuit.
I can't find resources that completely unload the upstage converter in a cascaded converter situation oddly.
My question is: When can the downstream converter load be included in the output impedance calculation of the upstream converter when performing the conservative Middlebrook check?

Hello, the problem with a front-end stage - e.g. the boost in the seminar - is that you need to impose an operating point before considering its output impedance. That is the reason for the presence of the load resistance. Without it, the converter operates in no-load conditions and the result is meaningless. Of course, you do not need that loading with a passive $LC$ filter. If you can, try to obtain a copy of the APEC 2017 seminar Small-Signal Stability and Subsystem Interactions
in Distributed Power Systems by D. Boroyevich, J. Liu and P. Mattavelli. They cover cascaded converters.

Hello, thanks for your response.  I can't seem to find a copy of that seminar but I'll keep looking.  I'm wondering about not just the binary choice of loading vs not loading at all, but what the load should actually be, if many different choices will result in valid but different operating points.  With a large load resistor, it would seem that the output impedance still has meaning for the light load case?  And choosing a heavier load seems to make it easier to close on middle brook, but that may be unrepresentative for the light load case.

Please drop me a mail. Yes, the output impedance will depend on the loading from the downstream converter and all cases must be explored.

Sounds good, I can't seem to find an email address on your profile, would you be able to post it here?

For the email, cbasso and the provider is orange.fr - cheers!

Email sent!  Many thanks

The Middlebrook stability criterion for cascaded dc-dc converters remains the same whether we talk about a front-end EMI filter driving a dc-dc converter or a front-end dc-dc converter driving a downstream switching converter: the closed-loop output impedance \$Z_{out}\$ of the front-end converter must be way smaller than the input impedance \$Z_{in}\$ of the loading dc-dc converter. During the measurement of \$Z_{out}\$, the front-end dc-dc converter must be kept at the right dc operating point, i.e. reproducing the loaded operating conditions by the downstream converter to keep its CCM (or DCM) operation. However, if you replace the downstream converter by a resistive load, this resistance will affect \$Z_{out}\$ and may corrupt the resulting graph.
The point raised by ardarn is valid, you cannot use a resistance for ensuring the correct dc operating point but, instead, a current source must be implemented. A perfect current source exhibits an infinite output resistance and, while it correctly fixes the bias point, it won't affect the output impedance.
In my APEC 2017 seminar, I used a resistance to load the CM boost converter while a current source should have been used. The slide has been corrected:

You can see the dc current source loading the converter and it is confirmed in various papers such the one referenced in my presentation:

When replacing the resistance by the current source in my simulation schematic, I did not see a noticeable difference on the \$Z_{out}\$ plot for this typical case. And the reason is due the large open-loop gain brought by the compensator. The closed-loop output impedance is equal to the open-loop output impedance divided by \$1+T(s)\$, \$T\$ being the compensated loop gain: \$Z_{out,CL}=\frac{Z_{out,OL}}{1+T(s)}\$. Therefore, the natural output impedance of the converter is already way smaller than the load resistance and replacing this latter by an infinite value does not alter the final result. Nevertheless, for correct experiments, a current source must be placed and I thank ardarn for bringing this point to my attention.
A final note on constant-current (CC) electronic sources: if you use one for fixing the dc operating point in the lab for measuring \$Z_{out,CL}\$, keep in mind that this equipment is also a control system which may interact with the converter during the ac sweep. I therefore recommend to run other sweeps where a pure resistance is connected to check that the graph obtained with the electronic CC source is within expected limits. Of course, in SPICE or SIMPLIS simulations, you don't have this issue.

Very intéresting ! Thank you for the question and the answer !
